# Due to not use in sentence

Tags: meaning, grammar, american-english, british-english

This is not due to or getting aggravated by malaria. 
Does it mean
This is not due to malaria and also this is not getting aggravated by malaria?

Comment: Yes, you have the meaning right; you may find the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) more useful in the future though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is exactly what it means. The 'not' extends over both 'due to' and 'aggravated by'; if you are familiar with the De Morgan laws of elementary logic, you'll recognise the negation of a disjunction being replaced by a conjunction of negations here.

Comment: I think you meant replacing, not being replaced.

Comment: I was referring to the transformation from 'This is not due to or getting aggravated by malaria' to 'This is not due to malaria and also this is not getting aggravated by malaria' in the original post.

Comment: I understand, but the sentence uses the form of `not (a or b)`, which is the negation of a disjunction. This is replacing the conjunction of negations in the explanation.

Comment: P.S. I am upvoting this answer to offset the malicious anonymous downvote.